# Preflight request for specific request is slow, for all browsers

Tags: angular, webapi2

I have one get type of request where options type of preflight request is taking so longer time(almost 40 sec) and in the response I am doing something like

```
<blob>response.blob()).
```

I have another request, too, but it works absolute fine.
I have checked the headers for all parameters of the options' request, but all appear to be the same.

What could be the cause ?